# UniqueID and ID

Tags: android, mysql, sql, unique-id

this is my first time working with DB in android. So I figured I would follow this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

As you can see, it makes you create a DB which as both an ID and something called UNIQUE_ID 
(there's even a function in PHP which creates a unique identifier)

ID is the primary key
UNIQUE_ID is set as UNIQUE

my question is. why do I need both? which one do I use for foreign keys?. Which is the point of having such a long a complicated ID?

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

The first `ID` it is the primary key for the table which is mainly a unique counter that updates every time a new row is created. It will keep increasing even if the row gets deleted.

`UNIQUE_ID` is an identifier created to keep track of users; think of it as if it were a unique `username` field

Comment: Thanks :)  so, which one should I use link other tables together?

Comment: I do not know what you mean. What do you want the tables to have in common?

Comment: Well, I have these tables:  ALBUMS - SONGS.  Inside songs I have a column called 'in_album' in which I want to store the album ID. Which ID should I store. the UNIQUE_ID or just the ID.

Comment: You need to store the ID that represents the album, not the row ID.